# How come that the "heroes" in physics are gone?

Tags: physics

I'm not sure if this question can be answered objectively but I still ask.

Once upon a time there were people like Galileo, Newton, Einstein, Feynman, Curie, Tesla, Dirac, Schrödinger, maybe Chopra, and all I don't mention. More recently maybe Hawking (about whom even a film was made, but maybe he had his wheelchair playing in favor of him). In Amsterdam and many other cities streets are named after these guys and girls.

Though I have my personal present hero, it seems that the past people don't have a counterbalance in recent or present day, again Hawing being the exception.

Why is it that almost all people know Einstein, Curie, Newton, or Hawking, but almost nobody knows Smolin, Witten, Verlinde (a Dutch physicist who invented an emergent gravity theory, who was even hailed on the Dutch news as the inventor of a completely new gravity), or Sabine what's-her-name (the German physicist who is popular on the internet)?

What was different in the past? Was the world still to be discovered (everybody knows Columbus or othe discovery travelers who were heading for the new world)? Like the invention (discovery) of the major fundaments?

Of course there are TV celebrities but I can hardly call them the heroes of physics. Maybe the advocates.

Truly coincidentally, I just read a piece in a Dutch newspaper, about the history of science (my translation):

> It was a time of titans. It was the time of scientists like Eduard Meyers, Jan-Hendrik Oort, Pieter Zeeman, and Johan Huizinga, individuals who blew their faculties to great heights. It was a time when Leiden university could imagine itself to be the best in Holland.

This is exactly what I mean. No more heroes anymore...

Comment: It's simply because the size of physics has grown immensely in the last 100 years. Theory and experiment both require large scale collaboration to make advancements the way the old 'titans' did. The last chapter of Segrè's "From X-rays to Quarks" explains this idea very nicely. There are still stand-out individuals, particularly on the theoretical side, but the work that needs doing in physics is bigger than ever before, and requires more man-power. There are also far more physicists today than there have ever been before. Physics, like math, is just getting bigger and bigger!

Comment: @SamGallagher So you would expect even more heroes. Im not sure if quantity has to do with this. You say, especially in the theoretical side. Why not in the exoerimental side? People risk their lives there.

Comment: you would not expect that. There are dozens, even hundreds of names on some publications, each person is responsible for some aspect of the work, particularly in experimental physics. No single person can be pointed at, and called the experimenter, it's more like a business. The organization is responsible for results, not particular individuals. On the theory side, the results tend to be incremental, because so many people are working so quickly, and everyone becomes specialized, everyone's publishing new results, reviews, proposals.

Comment: @SamGallagher Yeah. Its booming bussiness...

Comment: @SamGallagher Ive read a small part of the book you mentioned. Think I wanna read all of it!

Comment: Glad you liked it! Segre is awesome, helps you understand the development of modern physics from an "insider's" perspective, and it's pretty quick

Answer (score 5):

There are several reasons for this phenomenon.

1. What you are talking about is not really history of science, but history of mass media. That some physicists are household names while others
   are in relative obscurity. (For example you do not mention Stevin, Huygens or Hooke, Laplace or Hamilton, or even Maxwell (!!), and they are not among the names recognizable by everybody). This is a property of mass media to choose one "hero" at the expense of others. Public attention cannot concentrate on too many "heroes". (Some self-promotion can also play the role, sometimes).
2. Some time should pass before the really great discoveries are properly evaluated. Newton's greatness was not so much recognized in his lifetime as it was after. (Jonathan  Swift once wrote about Newton to his friend: "They say ridiculous things, for example that there is an
   an instrument maker in London, whole fame will be greater than mine!")
3. But the main reason is that physics is nowadays much larger than it used to be. There are much more great physicists and much more discoveries than there
   used to be at the time of Newton. And public attention has only very limited ability to digest this.
4. As someone said: "The system of the world can be discovered only once". In some sense, the most fundamental discoveries are made at earlier times, and later generations can only build on them. So as time goes, the fame of
   people like Newton, Maxwell, Einstein and Bohr increases all the time so the later discoverers can hardly compete. At the time when Newton lived, Archimedes and Descartes were more famous than he.
5. Newton's main discoveries are easy to explain to the general public: everyone can see comets, planets, rainbows and tides, and even imagine the shape of Earth. Electrical phenomena are not so clearly visible in the nature, but their discoveries immediately led to new technologies which everyone uses in daily life. Same with Quantum theory, it eventually led to many new technologies, including atomic energy. But modern theoretical physics is more remote from our daily life: nothing in our ordinary life is related to quarks, black holes or Higgs boson.

Comment: I was born in the first Contantijn Huygensstreet (the poetic brother of Huygens) and lived near the Maxwell street in Amsterdam. Of coutse, thanks to the newspaper (and radio) evertbody knew Einstein and Newton. But nowadays there are no Einsteins anymore. Maybe Hawking.

Comment: My little town has a Hamilton street crossing Lagrange street. But of course these are different Hamilton and Lagrange.

Comment: There are several living people whose contribution is no less than that of Hawking. For example, Roger Penrose. Hawking's name is more recognizable because of special circumstances of his life.

Comment: I think though that these point to the math-men.

Comment: Penrose crossed my mind too when asking. If he was in a wheelchair it would certainly be Penrose with the more fame.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Good observation re: Penrose.  For better or worse, the Einstein myth still defines the modern physics “brand”, although Hawking would comes in close second in the public imagination.

Comment: (+1) Regarding #1, the OP's names Feynman and Tesla were nowhere near their present name-recognition just a few decades ago. In fact, hardly anyone outside of math or physics had ever heard of Feynman until his 1985 book and his 1986 work on the space shuttle accident, and most everyone who did recognize his name (including me) only knew his name due to his Feynman diagrams and path integrals and noble prize for his QED work. An even more pronounced rise to fame in recent years is Alan Turing, who was mostly unknown aside from the "Turing Test", which I mostly knew from my philosophy classes.